# Automatically extract a factor from a sum of terms and rewrite the sum

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I would like to automatically extract the same factor of each term, and thus write a sum such as:

$$\frac{4 \sin (2 \pi  x)}{\pi }+\frac{4 \sin (6 \pi  x)}{3 \pi }+\frac{4 \sin (10 \pi 
   x)}{5 \pi }+\frac{4 \sin (14 \pi  x)}{7 \pi }$$

as

$$\frac{4}{\pi} \left( \sin(2 \pi x) + \frac{1}{3} \sin(6 \pi x) + \frac{1}{5} \sin (10 \pi x) + \frac{1}{7} \sin (14 \pi x)\right)$$

My goal is to have *Mathematica* find the factor (here $\frac{4}{\pi}$) automatically (not "by hand") and then perform the manipulations.

I've tried `Factor`, `DivideBy`, and several algebraic manipulation functions, but nothing works smoothly or fully automatically in such cases.  `Together` is almost appropriate, but not quite.

Here's code for the above:

```
(4 Sin[2 π x])/π + (4 Sin[
           6 π x])/(3 π) + (4 Sin[10 π x])/(5 π) + (4 Sin[
           14 π x])/(7 π) + (4 Sin[18 π x])/(9 π)
```

At @Nasser's request, here are a few similar made-up cases (in minimal form):

```
(5 E)/Sqrt[2] Cos[x] + (10 E)/(2 Sqrt[2]) Sin[2 x] + (15 E)/(3 Sqrt[2]) Cos[3 x] + (20 E)/(4 Sqrt[2]) Sin[4 x]

2/x Cos[x] + 4/x Exp[x] + 6/x Tan[x] + 8/x Cot[x]

5/Sqrt[3 x] Tan[x] + 10/Sqrt[3 x] Cot[x] + 15/Sqrt[3 x] Csc[x]

3/x Cos[x] + 6/x^2 Tan[x] + 9/x^2 Exp[x] + 12/x^3 Cot[x]
```

Comment: Please also enter the code for your expressions rather than just their images.

Comment: `FullSimplify`? If that's not good enough, you can try to tweak the `ComplexityFunction` to favour smaller integers more strongly

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately LCM does not work with Pi in there (it only works on rational numbers). So had to remove it temporarily to apply LCM then put it back in.

So this is not very general as it assumes Pi is there. I am sure there will be better and more general method. But this is what came to mind at this moment.

```
expr = 4/Pi*Sin[2*Pi*x] + 4/(3*Pi)*Sin[6*Pi*x] + 4/(5*Pi)*Sin[10*Pi*x] + 4/(7*Pi)*Sin[14*Pi*x]
res = Cases[List @@ expr, any_*Sin[_] -> any*Pi];
leastCommonMultipler = LCM[Sequence @@ res];
leastCommonMultipler/Pi*(Simplify[expr /. any_ -> Pi/leastCommonMultipler*any])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Definitely a help, thanks ($+1$).  But my expressions (many from Fourier analysis) will have $\pi$, $\sqrt{2}$, $e$, and such.  And most certainly all terms will not include, say, $\sin$.  The code must work with arbitrary functions, but with a single factor throughout.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork in this case, it might help and be useful if you could include in your question more examples that represent more of the input you want to transform. May be 4 or 5 such examples that typically show up. This will make it easier to give general solution that works for all. Because one solution that might work for one, might not work for another.

Answer (score 3):

Not the most elegant way, but perhaps good enough(?) or at least something on which others can build something smarter.

Given an expression

```
exp = (4 Sin[2 π x])/π + (4 Sin[
       6 π x])/(3 π) + (4 Sin[10 π x])/(5 π) + (4 Sin[
       14 π x])/(7 π) + (4 Sin[18 π x])/(9 π);
```

we can proceed to [**Sort**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html) it

```
(exp // Sort)[[1]]
```

and subsequently extract the numerical value we wish to factorize using [**Thread**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) and [**Variables**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variables.html) in the following way

```
% /. Thread[Variables[%] -> 1]
```

Then, it is pretty much straightforward to complete our exercise. We [**Solve**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) the following

```
Solve[exp == % xx, xx] // Expand // Flatten
```

and the final result we wish to obtain is

```
%%*(xx /. %)
```

Now, we can pack everything in a compound expression using a [**Module**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) and giving it a cool name, because why not?

```
davidgstork[exp_] := Module[{sorted, num, sltn},
   sorted = (exp // Sort)[[1]];
   num = sorted /. Thread[Variables[sorted] -> 1];
   sltn = Solve[exp == num*xx, xx] // Expand // Flatten;
   Return[num*(xx /. sltn)];
   ];
```

And we examine the examples provided by the OP

```
davidgstork[(4 Sin[2 π x])/\[Pi] + (4 Sin[
      6 π x])/(3 π) + (4 Sin[10 π x])/(5 π) + (4 Sin[
      14 π x])/(7 π) + (4 Sin[18 π x])/(9 π)]
davidgstork[(5 E)/Sqrt[2] Cos[x] + (10 E)/(2 Sqrt[2]) Sin[
    2 x] + (15 E)/(3 Sqrt[2]) Cos[3 x] + (20 E)/(4 Sqrt[2]) Sin[4 x]]
davidgstork[2/x Cos[x] + 4/x Exp[x] + 6/x Tan[x] + 8/x Cot[x]]
davidgstork[
 5/Sqrt[3 x] Tan[x] + 10/Sqrt[3 x] Cot[x] + 15/Sqrt[3 x] Csc[x]]
davidgstork[3/x Cos[x] + 6/x^2 Tan[x] + 9/x^2 Exp[x] + 12/x^3 Cot[x]]
```

> [image: results]

Final comment: it is the output of the 3$^{rd}$ and 4$^{th}$ examples that I don't particularly like, since I expect that @David would have preferred to have factored an overall $\tfrac{1}{x}$ and $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ respectively.

Comment: Good insight, and a big step in the right direction, but a few problems remain:  First, I don't think ***Sort[]*** will work in the arbitrary case.  And uyes, there should be a $1/x$ in the factor for your example 3.  (But oh... what a cool name!)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork glad you found this helpful. Some comments: yes, I kind of had the idea that `Sort` would not work in the most general case, though perhaps a good hint on how to approach. About the factors that I mentioned and you, also, explained I still have no clue on how to get those....Finally, pertaining to the name of the `Module` function, I was expecting that you would perhaps like it :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
expr1 = (4 Sin[2 π x])/π + (4 Sin[
       6 π x])/(3 π) + (4 Sin[10 π x])/(5 π) + (4 Sin[
       14 π x])/(7 π) + (4 Sin[18 π x])/(9 π);
expr2 = (5 E)/Sqrt[2] Cos[x] + (10 E)/(2 Sqrt[2]) Sin[
     2 x] + (15 E)/(3 Sqrt[2]) Cos[3 x] + (20 E)/(4 Sqrt[2]) Sin[4 x];
expr3 = 2/x Cos[x] + 4/x Exp[x] + 6/x Tan[x] + 8/x Cot[x];
expr4 = 5/Sqrt[3 x] Tan[x] + 10/Sqrt[3 x] Cot[x] + 15/Sqrt[3 x] Csc[x];
expr5 = 3/x Cos[x] + 6/x^2 Tan[x] + 9/x^2 Exp[x] + 12/x^3 Cot[x];
trigs = Sin | Cos | Tan | Csc | Sec | Cot;
expr = {expr1, expr2, expr3, expr4, expr5};
lcm[expr_] := List @@ expr // Cases[#, _?NumberQ, 2] & // Apply[LCM]
gcd[expr_] := List @@ expr // Cases[#, _?NumberQ, 2] & // Apply[GCD]
lcms = lcm /@ expr;
gcds = gcd /@ expr;
ifactors = List @@ expr // Map[Apply[Intersection]];
fc = Transpose[{lcms, gcds}] // 
    DeleteCases[#, Except[_Integer], {2}] & // Map[Min];

res = MapThread[Row[
     {Times[If[Head@#2 === Times, 1, #1], #2 ]
      , "("
      , (#3/(If[Head@#2 === Times, 1, #1] #2)) // Distribute
      , ")"
      }] &
   
   , {
    fc, ifactors, expr
    }
   ];
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the work ($+1$), but look at your last example:  it found the factor $3$ but should have found $\frac{3}{x}$.  I wonder why it didn't get the full factor.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't been able to get the common factor `x` out from `Plus[Times[9,Power[E,x],Power[x,-2]],Times[3,Power[x,-1],Cos[x]],Times[12,Power[x,-3],Cot[x]],Times[6,Power[x,-2],Tan[x]]]`. Will have to think more about it.